# Knockout not passing index value of the array to the view model

Tags: knockout.js

I have a button inside my `foreach` binding

```
<button class="Button" type="button" data-bind="text: $root.UploadFile, 
 event: { click: function (data, e) {e.preventDefault(); $('#upload').click();}}"></button>
```

When i click the button i call the following

```
<input id="upload" type="file" style="width: 100%; display: none" 
   data-bind="event: { change: function(a,b){ $root.FileChanged($index,a,b)}  }" />
```

In the view model, I have this function

```
private FileChanged = (index,vm, evt) => {

}
```

However when the function gets called, the index of the array is always "0". I am trying to get the index of the `foreach` array by doing `$index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because all the `input`s in your `foreach` have the same `id="upload"`. When you click on any of the buttons, it'll always trigger the first `input`. And that's why you're getting zero every time. So, change the `id` of the inputs based on the `index()` using the [`attr`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding. Now the `input`s will have ids "*upload0*", "*upload1*" etc. You also need to change the `click` binding to trigger the respective ids:

```js
const viewModel = function() {
    const self = this;

    self.array = ko.observableArray([0, 1]);
    self.FileChanged = (index) => {
        alert(index);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: array -->
<button type="button" data-bind="event: { click: function (data, e) {e.preventDefault(); $('#upload' + $index()).click();}}">Upload</button>
<input type="file" style="width: 100%; display: none" data-bind="attr: {id:'upload' +$index() }, event: { change: function(a,b){$root.FileChanged($index(),a,b)}  }" />
<!-- /ko -->
```